# NSXMLDocument class in iPhone Device 2.2

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

i developed one iPhone application, i have used the class "NSXMLDocument" it is working fine in simulator 2.2. but when i select Device 2.2 it is not woking.. i got the error message that

" error: 'NSXMLDocument' undeclared (first use in this function)",,

any idea to solve this ..

by Abjal

Answer (score 4):

NSXMLDocument doesn't exist on the actual device as its too resource intensive - you'll have to use NSXMLParser instead, look [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html) for how to implement it.